# ajax requst with php code (without php file)

Tags: php, ajax, file

I am doing some table that loads data from sql with limit 20 and offset 0, i want on click on next page number, ajax request that will change that offset to 20 and display the resulting data. so i have nice php function that does it perfectly but i do not wish to make a new php file just for ajax.

here is my [table pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kelXg.png)

```
<table class="ui red table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>თარიღი</th>
            <th>მასალა</th>
            <th>რაოდენობა</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?PHP
            $mainStockTable = new EchoStock($mysqli, "mainstock", 20);
            $mainStockTable->ManualTransactionListTable(0);
        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">
          <div class="ui right floated pagination menu">
            <a class="icon item">
              <i class="left chevron icon"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="item">1</a>
            <a class="item">2</a>
            <a class="item">3</a>
            <a class="item">4</a>
            <a class="icon item">
              <i class="chevron left icon"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

So what i want is something like:

the PHP `ManualTransactionList` Table echos  as many times as needed

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $pageNum = this.text();

  $.AJAX({
     PHPcode: <?PHP
                $mainStockTable = new EchoStock($mysqli, "mainstock", 20);
                $mainStockTable->ManualTransactionListTable(0);
            ?>
     success: function(response){
        $('table').html(response);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make an AJAX request without a file:

This here:

```
    $.AJAX({
     PHPcode: <?PHP
                $mainStockTable = new EchoStock($mysqli, "mainstock", 20);
                $mainStockTable->ManualTransactionListTable(0);
            ?>
     success: function(response){
        $('table').html(response);
    }
```

The PHP code only gets executed **server-side** not client-side.The client, a.k.a. the browser does not "understand" PHP, only the server does.

Comment: i know php is server side.
So but i thought maybe javascript or jquery have any option to do this, like create temporary file serverside execute and delete or smthing like that.
the browser doesnt understand php is obvious

Comment: AJAX executes a PHP script remotely, it needs a URL. Even if JavaScript had a feature like that how could they know what server will run the script?  With what session data, cookies, e.t.c? It's simply not possible. You can't avoid creating a new .php file